# Convert stdClass Object in to multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have `$positions` stdClass Object as below

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [position] => am
            [label] => Account Manager
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [position] => agn
            [label] => Agent
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [position] => bdev
            [label] => Business Development
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [position] => fin
            [label] => Finance
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [position] => hr
            [label] => Human Resource
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [position] => it
            [label] => Information Technology
        )

)
```

I want to convert it as an multidimensional array so I beed ut to `return it into a function` and reuse it as per need.. something like below

```
array(

    array (
        'id' => 1,
        'position' => 'admin',
        'label' => 'Administrator'
    ),

    array (
        'id' => 2,
        'position' => 'am',
        'label' => 'Account Manager'
    ),

    array (
        'id' => 3,
        'position' => 'hr',
        'label' => 'Human Resource'
    ),
);
```

I am not sure what exactly array form would be but I want to return array so I can get entire table and than can use it into the system.

I have tried below but it is not giving output as I want

```
foreach($positions as $position){
    $array[] = $position->id;
    $array[] = $position->label;
    $array[] = $position->position;
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($array),'</pre>';
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => Account Manager
    [2] => am
    [3] => 6
    [4] => Agent
    [5] => agn
    [6] => 5
    [7] => Business Development
    [8] => bdev
    [9] => 4
    [10] => Finance
    [11] => fin
    [12] => 1
    [13] => Human Resource
    [14] => hr
    [15] => 3
    [16] => Information Technology
    [17] => it
)
```

This is obvious output but I need to know how can I get return multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is flat array because you're adding your elements into array via `[]`. To fix that, add elements as array to your main array, like:

```
foreach($positions as $position)
{
    $array[] = [
       'id'      => $position->id,
       'label'   => $position->label,
       'position'=> $position->position
    ];
}
```

In PHP<5.4 there's no possibility to use `[]` for array definition, so then use `array()` instead.

Comment: This works nice just wonder why my editor showing me syntax error for array box.. but not in browser output.. may be editor doesn't support latest version of PHP?

Comment: @JatinSoni yes, that also may be (upgrade it then)

Comment: That's your decision. Because `get_object_vars()` is more flexible (i.e. will do stuff automatically) - but on the other hand, explicitly recounting of array keys is good because you'll know exactly which keys will be in result array (so if something will change, that will not affect your result)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_object_vars():](https://www.php.net/get_object_vars)

```
$array = array();
foreach($positions as $pos){
  $array[] = get_object_vars($pos);
}
```

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/5I8D4u)

Be careful of the accessibility level of the variable:

```
 Gets the accessible non-static properties of the given object according to scope.
```

Comment: This gives the same output as Alma Do code.. just wonder which method is the best for future proof and error resistance?

Comment: See @Alma Do comment, mainly it's a matter of control you want to have over the content

Answer (score 0):

To handle this sort of thing in my projects, I've just type-casted it:

```
$positions_array = (array)$positions;
```

This will keep your existing structure, but turn it into an array.